# Converting CSV file to GEXF file format using javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way which will help in converting a csv into GEXF file format using javascript

Answer (score 1):

CSV is just a table containing data, but GEXF contains nodes & edges. You have to make your converter yourself to suit your source data.